# Python how to detect the entire head's bounding box

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, image-recognition

I am using Python and cv2 for face detection. But I need the entire head rather than just the face (to later seperate the head from the backgroud)

I found how to seperate the face using cv2 and haarcascades like [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/)

But I am looking for a way to get the entire head. Right until the point where the top of the head ends. Not just the rectangle around the face.

I considered just adding XXX percents of height, but this is not accurate and will create issues with the background later.

How can I get the outline of the head rather than the face?

Comment: i think you'll end up having to create a haarcascade for heads honestly, even though faces are parts of heads and intuitively it might seem like all you need to do is evolve the face algorithm a little, i think it's still an entirely different classification, and you're probably better off starting from scratch.

Comment: @vencaslac can you point out for some resources needed to do it? How many images would you expect to suffice? Links to code maybe? Will that work for the entire body also?

Comment: @vencaslac is there any suitable dataset for that?